# How is Brexit affecting the interactions between citizens?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

How does Brexit affect the society's attitude towards each other?

Are people becoming more hostile towards each other over the voting?

And lastly, do xenophobic parties voice their opinions more now than before?

Comment: I have removed future form of the question to avoid speculation. Also, Brexit is (rather long) process that has already begun, so I think questions in this form (present) are more answerable.

Answer (score 3):

> Are people becoming more hostile towards each other over the voting?

I live in the UK.  I have numerous friends who live there too, but are of non-UK origin.  Many of them have told me about increased incidents of racism after the vote.  This is born out in official statistics, see https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/brexit/2018/03/19/hate-crime-did-spike-after-the-referendum-even-allowing-for-other-factors/ for some analysis

> And lastly, do xenophobic parties voice their opinions more now than before?

Not really, since the Brexit debate xenophobia has become normalised in UK political debate.  So there is no need for special xenophobic parties and their support has declined.  For example, the last BNP councillor recently retired in Lancashire and in August 2018
[UKIP had 23,600 members, compared to over 34,293 reported in December 2016.](https://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/ResearchBriefing/Summary/SN05125)

In Europe more widely, some do believe that [Brexit has perked up the far right](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/jun/28/brexit-europe-far-right-rightwing-extremists-politics-terrorism)  For example Marine Le Pen of the National Rally in France was the closest contender against Macron and she has [praised Brexit](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/jun/24/european-far-right-hails-britains-brexit-vote-marine-le-pen)